# Neo4J - Extracting graph as a list based on relationship strength

Tags: graph, neo4j, relationship

I have a typical friend of friend graph database i.e. a social network database. The requirement is to extract all the nodes as a list in such a way that the least connected nodes appear together in the list and the most connected nodes are placed further apart in the list.

Basically its asking a graph to be represented as a list and I'm not sure if we can really do that. For e.g. if A is related to B with strength 10, B is related to C with strength 80, A to C is 20
then how to place this in a list ?
A, B, C - no because then A is distant from C relatively more than B which is not the case
A, C, B - yes because A and B are less related that A,C and C,B.

With 3 nodes its very simple but with lot of nodes - is it possible to put them in a list based on relationship strength ?

Comment: Can you give more sample input/output?

Comment: For e.g. a sample query set is `CREATE (a:Person {id: '01', name: 'A' })
CREATE (b:Person {id: '02', name: 'B' })
CREATE (c:Person {id: '03', name: 'C' })
CREATE (d:Person {id: '04', name: 'D' })
CREATE (e:Person {id: '05', name: 'E' })
CREATE (f:Person {id: '06', name: 'F' })`

Comment: `CREATE
(a)-[:RELATED_TO {Strength: 30} ]-(b),
(a)-[:RELATED_TO {Strength: 60} ]-(c),
(a)-[:RELATED_TO {Strength: 10} ]-(d),
(b)-[:RELATED_TO {Strength: 15} ]-(c),
(b)-[:RELATED_TO {Strength: 80} ]-(e),
(d)-[:RELATED_TO {Strength: 100} ]-(e),
(c)-[:RELATED_TO {Strength: 15} ]-(f),
(f)-[:RELATED_TO {Strength: 45} ]-(a),
(f)-[:RELATED_TO {Strength: 40} ]-(d);`

Comment: Each node in this sample is connected by relationship properly Strength - thats numeric. Now how can I list these nodes in a way that they are ordered based on their strength in descending order

Comment: Sample output would be good, especially in the form of Cypher output.

Comment: Also, you can edit the question to avoid filling up too many comments.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think this is maybe what you want. An inverse of the shortestPath traversal with weights. If not, tell me how the output should be.

http://console.neo4j.org/r/n8npue

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*]-(m) // search all paths
WHERE n <> m
  AND ALL (x IN nodes(p) WHERE length([x2 IN nodes(p) WHERE x2=x])=1) // this filters simple paths
RETURN [n IN nodes(p)| n.name] AS names, // get the names out
  reduce(acc=0, r IN relationships(p)| acc + r.Strength) AS totalStrength // calculate total strength produced by following this path
ORDER BY length(p) DESC , totalStrength ASC // get the max length (hopefully a full traversal), and the minimum strength
LIMIT 1
```

This is not going to be efficient for a large graph, but I think it's definitely doable--probably needs using the traversal/graphalgo API shortest path functionality if you need speed on a large graph.

Comment: Thanks Wes, but then if you see the results it comes as [E, B, C, F, D, A] where i can see E and A are placed further apart, though there is no relationship between them, the thought is to keep people who are strongly related further apart i.e. E and A should be next to each other and E & D should be further apart.

Comment: Anyhow, I think the question is a little early - I'm trying to define the problem statement with more parameters, will post here when i have more details.

Comment: I think I got my problem statement - basically I want to find out frequent datasets in a neo4j database i.e. implementation of Apriori algorithm in Neo4J. Is this existing today in Neo4j ?

Comment: To add further - the question is - how can we mine patterns in Neo4J i.e. lets say I just want to find out all patterns and their existing frequency in my Neo4J database for e.g. A,E,F,G - occurs in 20 invoices - E,L,A - in 5 invoices, A,G - in 2 invoices etc i.e. all patterns with its frequeny - then how do we do it ? For relational db - we have algorithms implemented like Apriori (ARules package), but does something like this exists for Neo4J today ?

Comment: Hey Deepesh, was it possible to find a way to implement Apriori in neo4j ? 
Thanks